# Extracting GTIN (regex)

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking to extract GTIN codes from documents, they're 8, 12, 13 or 14 digit numbers. So I'm doing this:

```
$html = '8 digit 12345678 and now 12 digit 123456789012';

$extractGTIN = '/\d{7}$|^\d{11}$|^\d{12}$|^\d{13}/mi'; 
preg_match_all($extractGTIN, $html, $barcodes);

echo print_r ($barcodes, 1);
```

... but unexpectedly, it returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6789012
        )

)
```

Comment: `^` and `$` are for the start and end of the **string**, not of the pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have not anchored the alternatives properly, use word boundaries. Instead of alternations, you may use an optional group here:

```
/\b\d{8}(?:\d{4,6})?\b/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NIRVzl/2).

**Details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `\d{8}` - 8 digits
- `(?:\d{4,6})?` - an optional sequence of 4, 5 or 6 digits (thus, matching all in all 8, 12, 13, 14 digits)
- `\b` - trailing word boundary.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/EbODOJ):

```
$text = '8 digit 12345678 and now 12 digit 123456789012';
$extractGTIN = '/\b\d{8}(?:\d{4,6})?\b/'; 
preg_match_all($extractGTIN, $text, $barcodes);
print_r($barcodes[0]);
// => Array ( [0] => 12345678 [1] => 123456789012 )
```